# Wavemaker- How to add new user?

Tags: crud, wavemaker

Today I am using WaveMaker for the very first time and using WaveMaker's Security.

I want to add a 'Register User' button along side Login, Though i have added the button on UI level but don't know how to bind it with database(sqlServer).

As the name suggests this button will add new users in database, how to do it?

what steps should I follow after adding button?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new user, maybe you can add some layer (or dialog form) that has the inputs that you need to capture, then, in the "create" button of your form, you have to connecto to the service that is connected to the database.

To understand how you can connect a button to the database follow the next tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofzMBDtAz_w

regards